# C# Webservice Client Calculate each Security Header Element Independently

Tags: c#, xml, web-services

I am trying to create a soap envelope manually and trying to create the security header like the following. Because of the strict namespace validations in the webservice server side the request is always failing with Invalid Security Header Error. Is there a way in C# .NET to form the entire Signature elements line by line. Following is the Output XML I am expecting.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:oas1="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:msg:irstransmitterstatusrequest" xmlns:urn1="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:ext:aca:air:7.0" xmlns:urn2="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:common" xmlns:urn3="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:msg:acasecurityheader">
    <soapenv:Header xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
        <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
            <ds:Signature Id="SIG-E68EBBF1696C5DD4AA143353323390579" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                <ds:SignedInfo>
                    <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#WithComments" />
                    <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
                    <ds:Reference URI="#TS-82E7E6716E615C14D6144736030985954">
                        <ds:Transforms>
                            <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                                <InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="wsse wsa oas1 soapenv urn urn1 urn2 urn3" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                            </ds:Transform>
                        </ds:Transforms>
                        <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
                        <ds:DigestValue>[Digest_Value_Replaced]</ds:DigestValue>
                    </ds:Reference>
                    <ds:Reference URI="#id-82E7E6716E615C14D6144736030986559">
                        <ds:Transforms>
                            <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                                <InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="oas1 soapenv urn1 urn2 urn3" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                            </ds:Transform>
                        </ds:Transforms>
                        <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
                        <ds:DigestValue>[Digest_Value_Replaced]</ds:DigestValue>
                    </ds:Reference>
                    <ds:Reference URI="#id-82E7E6716E615C14D6144736030986558">
                        <ds:Transforms>
                            <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                                <InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="wsa oas1 soapenv urn1 urn2 urn3" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                            </ds:Transform>
                        </ds:Transforms>
                        <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
                        <ds:DigestValue>[Digest_Value_Replaced]</ds:DigestValue>
                    </ds:Reference>
                </ds:SignedInfo>
                <ds:SignatureValue>[Signature_Value_Replaced]</ds:SignatureValue>
                <ds:KeyInfo Id="KI-82E7E6716E615C14D6144736030986456">
                    <wsse:SecurityTokenReference wsu:Id="STR-82E7E6716E615C14D6144736030986457" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
                        <wsse:KeyIdentifier EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3">[Cert_Value_Replaced]</wsse:KeyIdentifier>
                    </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
                </ds:KeyInfo>
            </ds:Signature>
            <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="TS-82E7E6716E615C14D6144736030985954">
                <wsu:Created>2016-03-23T09:53:23:55Z</wsu:Created>
                <wsu:Expires>2016-03-23T10:03:23:55Z</wsu:Expires>
            </wsu:Timestamp>
        </wsse:Security>
        <urn:ACABusinessHeader wsu:Id="id-82E7E6716E615C14D6144736030986558" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
            <urn1:UniqueTransmissionId>uuid:SYS12:tcc_cd::T</urn1:UniqueTransmissionId>
            <urn2:Timestamp>2016-03-23T09:53:23:55Z</urn2:Timestamp>
        </urn:ACABusinessHeader>
        <urn3:ACASecurityHeader/>
        <wsa:Action>RequestSubmissionStatusDetail</wsa:Action>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <urn:ACABulkRequestTransmitterStatusDetailRequest version="1.0" wsu:Id="id-82E7E6716E615C14D6144736030986559" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
            <urn1:ACABulkReqTrnsmtStsReqGrpDtl>
                <urn2:ReceiptId>[ReceiptId_Value_Replaced]</urn2:ReceiptId>
            </urn1:ACABulkReqTrnsmtStsReqGrpDtl>
        </urn:ACABulkRequestTransmitterStatusDetailRequest>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually this should be done by some infrastructure code like WCF client binding (or the old WSE extensions) or some other Ws-Security library.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms977327.aspx

But if you must, you can use the SignedXml class from System.Security.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.xml.signedxml(v=vs.110).aspx

There is a strict workflow that you need to follow (elements references, transformation, canonicalization, hash algorithm, key algorithm, key types) and it usually depends on the service which is the one setting the rules.

These peculiarities are actually the reason why most of the developer world *hated* SOAP and went about with REST.